# how to update state according to id in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatist as follows:

```
const displayMessageList = (message) => {
    return (
      <View>
        {message.length > 0 && enableMoreMessages ? (
          <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => fetchMoreMessages()}>
              <Text>More</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        ) : null}
        <FlatList data={message} renderItem={displayMessageRenderItem} />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

where displaymessagerenderitem is as follows:

```
const displayMessageRenderItem = ({ item }) => {
    var audio;
    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
        {item.type == 2 ? (
          <View>
            {item.media_list && item.media_list.length > 0 && (
              <View style={styles.servermessage}>
                {item.media_list[0].media_url ? (
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: item.media_list[0].media_url }}
                    style={{ height: 300, width: 300 }}
                    resizeMode="contain"
                  />
                ) : null}
              </View>
            )}
            <View style={styles.servermessage}>
              <Text style={styles.servertext}>{item.message}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.server_time_to_display}>
                {item.time_to_display}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        ) : (
            <View style={{ alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
              {item.media_list && item.media_list.length > 0 && (
                <View style={styles.sendermessage}>
                  {item.type_of_message_content === "image" ? (
                    item.media_list[0].media_url ? (
                      <Image
                        source={{ uri: item.media_list[0].media_url }}
                        style={{ height: 300, width: 300 }}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                      />
                    ) : null
                  ) : item.media_list[0].media_url ? (
                    soundpause === true ? (
                      <>

                        <View
                          style={{
                            flexDirection: "row",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            alignItems: "center",
                          }}
                        >
                          {item.sender && item.sender.pic_url != "" && (
                            <Image
                              source={{ uri: item.sender.pic_url }}
                              style={{ height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 25 }}
                              resizeMode="contain"
                            />
                          )}
                          <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() =>
                              listenaudio(item.media_list[0].media_url, item.id)
                            }
                          >
                            <AntDesignIcon
                              name="caretright"
                              size={25}
                              color="#E23744"
                            />
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                          <Image
                            source={Images.seekline}
                            style={{ height: 3 }}
                            tintColor="#E23744"
                          />
                        </View>
                      </>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                          <View
                            style={{
                              flexDirection: "row",
                              justifyContent: "center",
                              alignItems: "center",
                            }}
                          >
                            {item.sender && item.sender.pic_url != "" && (
                              <Image
                                source={{ uri: item.sender.pic_url }}
                                style={{ height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 25 }}
                                resizeMode="contain"
                              />
                            )}
                            <TouchableOpacity
                              onPress={() =>
                                listenaudio(item.media_list[0].media_url)
                              }
                            >
                              <AntDesignIcon
                                name="caretright"
                                size={25}
                                color="#B2B2B2"
                              />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <Image source={Images.seekline} style={{ height: 3 }} />
                          </View>
                          {/* <Text>{item.media_list[0].media_url}</Text> */}
                        </>
                      )
                  ) : null}

                  <Text style={styles.sender_time_to_display}>
                    {item.time_to_display}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              )}
              {item.message != "" && (
                <View style={styles.sendermessage}>
                  <Text style={styles.sendertext}>{item.message}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.sender_time_to_display}>
                    {item.time_to_display}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              )}
            </View>
          )}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

inside listenaudio() I want to set the state of pause to true/false but only for the selected item :

```
const listenaudio = (audio, id) => {
setsoundpause(!soundpause);
    console.log('audio', audio)
    var sound = new Sound(audio, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
        return;
      }
      // loaded successfully
      console.log('duration in seconds: ' + sound.getDuration() + 'number of channels: ' + sound.getNumberOfChannels());

      // Play the sound with an onEnd callback
      sound.play((success) => {
        if (success) {
          console.log('successfully finished playing');
        } else {
          console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
        }
      });
    });
    console.log('listen to', sound);
    sound.setVolume(1);

  };
```

However when I select the item all state for all the items in the list are changing, could anyone please help me out here?

Any leads would be great.
Let me know if anything else is required.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is `soundpause` just defined as `const [soundpause,setsoundpause] = useState(false)` right now?

Comment: as an object, I am not sure how to update it accordingly, could please provide a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage playing sound with id

```
const [playingId,setPlayingId] = useState(0)
```

set id in listenaudio function

```
setPlayingId(id);
```

and comapre in displayMessageRenderItem

```
playingId == item.id
```

Comment: Glad to help :)